# apache/mod_wsgi: How do I spawn specific number of processes?

Tags: mod-wsgi, apache

How do I spawn a specific number of processes in Apache when using mod_wsgi with the WSGIDaemonProcess setting?

I have my VirtualHost setup with the following (as a test):

```
WSGIDaemonProcess webserver user=webserver group=webserver processes=24 threads=8 display-name=%{GROUP} python-path=/var/virtualenv/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

While my httpd.conf is setup as follows:

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    1
MaxSpareServers    8
ServerLimit       24
MaxClients        24
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

Note, that I'm running a very constrained 256MB server with PostgreSQL database installed as well.

However, system shows far more than 24 processes for apache (more than 30). I expected that if I set the ServerLimit to the same as processes in WSGIDaemonProcess it would run at the constant 24. However, there seems to be a bunch of spare processes running for unknown reasons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ServerLimit directive has got nothing to do with mod_wsgi daemon mode. The 'processes' option to WSGIDaemonProcess is what specifies how many daemon processes mod_wsgi will create. It is a static number and not a dynamic number so just set it to how many you need. For that number of threads per process, there is no point setting it to more that 'processes=3' to start with as you are limited to 24 concurrent requests in the Apache child worker processes which proxy requests to the mod_wsgi daemon processes, so not possible to handle any more requests than that.

In general, if you are running in a memory constrained environment, then you should not be using prefork MPM but worker MPM. Is there a reason you must, such as needing to run PHP code as well? If not, change the MPM used.

How else you could configure things really depends on your code, response times and request throughput, which only you know.

Comment: I'm running pre-fork, primarily because I don't know if it has any effect on django and concurrency. Is that something I should even be worried about? Also, if 'processes' option for WSGIDaemonProcess is independent, is there a way to prevent Apache from spawning unused processes? I only use this server to serve mod_wsgi/django projects.

Comment: Because you are running Django in daemon mode (presuming you have properly delegated it using WSGIProcessGroup) and so Django not running in the Apache child processes which are covered by the MPM setting, then doesn't matter whether you use prefork or worker MPM. To keep memory down and avoid spinning up processes you don't really need, you should use worker MPM though and not preform MPM. Change the MPM and you will straight away eliminate the extra processes as child workers will use multithreading instead.

Comment: How can I verify daemon mode is properly delegated?

Comment: Also, as I change the MPM to Worker, there will only be one process with threads (as needed). Threads don't get spawned until there is a need i.e. serving request which it never does in my case?

Comment: To verify whether using daemon mode, read 'http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/CheckingYourInstallation#Embedded_Or_Daemon_Mode'. Threads are created up front in a pool and reused. They are not created on demand nor subsequently destroyed. They persist for the whole process. You should configure things with minimum number of threads you really need, else the remain unused but active threads still consume memory.